# How can I use CallerArgumentExpression with Visual Studio 2022 and .net Standard 2.0 or .net 4.8?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

With Visual Studio 2022 and .net 6.0 we have the new [`CallerArgumentExpression` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/caller-argument-expression) that we can use to *"capture the expressions passed to a method, to enable better error messages in diagnostic/testing APIs and reduce keystrokes"*.

For example, we can write a class to check for null method arguments like so:

```
public static class Contract
{
    public static T RequiresArgNotNull<T>(T? item, [CallerArgumentExpression("item")] string? expression = default, string? message = null)
        where T : class
    {
        if (item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(
                expression ?? "<unknown>",
                message ?? (expression != null ? "Requires " + expression + " != null" : "RequiresArgNotNull() failed."));

        return item;
    }
}
```

Which can be used like so:

```
using static ClassLibrary1.Contract; // To allow just putting RequiresArgNotNull()

...

static void test(string theString)
{
    RequiresArgNotNull(theString); // Note that we do NOT need to pass the parameter
                                   // name as a separate string.
    Console.WriteLine(theString);
}
```

If `theString` is null, an exception will be thrown which looks like this:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Requires theString != null
Parameter name: theString
```

**I would like to be able to use this feature with .net 4.8 and/or .net Standard 2.0. Is this possible?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2022, you can use `CallerArgumentExpression` with .net 4.8 and/or .net Standard 2.0 by defining a local `internal` implementation of `CallerArgumentExpressionAttribute` like so:

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    internal sealed class CallerArgumentExpressionAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public CallerArgumentExpressionAttribute(string parameterName)
        {
            ParameterName = parameterName;
        }

        public string ParameterName { get; }
    }
}
```

Note that you must use the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` namespace in order for this to work correctly. By making this implementation `internal` you can guarantee that it won't conflict with any system-defined implementation.

This will compile as a `.net Standard 2.0` target, so it can be also used by assemblies that target `.net 4.8`, `.net Core 3.1` and so on.

Also note that you still require Visual Studio 2022 and its SDK for this to work - if you try to use Visual Studio 2019 it will compile OK but the argument will be null.

You can include the above class in the assembly that uses `CallerArgumentExpression` and it will work as expected.

---

**Sample .net Standard 2.0 class library providing `Contract.RequiresArgNotNull()`:**

(This sample assembly is using namespace `ClassLibrary1` for brevity.)

Project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>8</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

CallerArgumentExpression.cs:

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    #if !NET6_0_OR_GREATER

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    internal sealed class CallerArgumentExpressionAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public CallerArgumentExpressionAttribute(string parameterName)
        {
            ParameterName = parameterName;
        }

        public string ParameterName { get; }
    }

    #endif
}
```

Contract.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

#nullable enable

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public static class Contract
    {
        public static T RequiresArgNotNull<T>(T? item, [CallerArgumentExpression("item")] string? expression = default, string? message = null)
            where T : class
        {
            if (item == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(
                    expression ?? "<unknown>",
                    message ?? (expression != null ? "Requires " + expression + " != null" : "RequiresArgNotNull() failed."));

            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample console application demonstrating the use of `RequiresArgNotNull()`:**

```
using System;
using static ClassLibrary1.Contract;

#nullable enable

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                test(null!);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());   
            }
        }

        static void test(string theString)
        {
            RequiresArgNotNull(theString);
            Console.WriteLine(theString);
        }
    }
}
```

This will output the following exception message (for my particular build):

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Requires theString != null
Parameter name: theString
   at ClassLibrary1.Contract.RequiresArgNotNull[T](T item, String expression, String message) in E:\Test\cs9\ConsoleApp1\ClassLibrary1\Contract.cs:line 18
   at Demo.Program.test(String theString) in E:\Test\cs9\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 25
   at Demo.Program.Main() in E:\Test\cs9\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 14
```

Comment: Thanks for that! This is such a great feature!   
Do you know any library that has many of these helpers baked in? (target `netstandard2.0`)

Comment: @kapsiR Unfortunately not - it's all too new for netstandard2.0. See https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-11-callerargumentexpression-and-throw-helpers/ and https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ArgumentNullException.cs#L67-L69 for some implementations that you could model your own on.

Comment: Check out Ardalis.GuardClauses on NuGet.